# if $A$ is open in $M$ and $B$ is open in $N$, then $A \times B$ is open in $M \times N$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

where $d((m_1,n_1),(m_2,n_2)) = d_M(m_1,m_2) + d_N(n_1,n_2)$

By some propositions, $A$ is open in $M$ if there exist an open set $K_1$ such that $A = M \cap K_1$

Also, there exist an open set $K_2$ such that $B = N \cap K_2$

$A \times B = (M \cap K_1) \times (N \cap K_2)$

$= (M \times N) \cap (K_1 \times K_2)$

does this mean I have to now prove that $K_1 \times K_2$ is open? how?

I am confused. I don't think this is the right approach.

thanks.

Comment: Consider a point $z\in A\times B$ and show that there exist an open ball around $z$ that is contained in $A\times B$.

Comment: Note that $\max(|a|,|b|)\le |a|+|b| \le 2 \max(|a|,|b|)$

Comment: You might want to review your definition of an open set in a metric space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in a metric space $(X,\rho)$, a set $U$ is open **iff** for any $x \in U$, there exists some $\epsilon>0$ such that $B(x,\epsilon) \subset U$,
where $B(x,\epsilon) = \{ y \in X | \rho(x,y) < \epsilon \}$.

Second, it is easy to see that $\max(|a|,|b|)\le |a|+|b|$. We will use this below.

Suppose $A,B$ are open in their respective spaces. Choose $(a,b) \in A \times B$, and pick $\epsilon>0$ such that $B_M(a,\epsilon) \subset A$, $B_N(b,\epsilon) \subset B$.

Now suppose $(x,y) \in B((a,b), \epsilon)$. Then $d_M(a,x)+d_N(b,y) < \epsilon$, so we have $d_M(a,x) < \epsilon$ and $d_N(b,y) < \epsilon$, hence 
$(x,y) \in A \times B$. Hence $B((a,b), \epsilon) \subset A \times B$ and so
$A \times B$ is open.

Answer (score 0):

You write: $ A $ is open in $M$ if there exists an open set $K_1$ such that $A=M\bigcap  K_1$.
You need this if you have to do with a subspace.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.